# I need help wiring a double switch in the bathroom

Tags: wiring, lighting

I have a new build.  I need help connecting the wires to the switches in the bathroom.  Here is what I have:
a double switch: one runs 2 lights and the other runs the exhaust fan

I have 3 black wires, 3 white wires and 3 neutral wires

for the switch running the 2 lights I connected the 2 white wires together and connected the black wires to the screws on the light switch and the neutral to the switch as well.  This switch is working fine.

for the switch running the exhaust fan i hooked a black and white and neutral to this one and it will not work.

Should I have somehow hooked the single exhaust switch into the other switch?  If so how do I do this.

Comment: When you say "neutral wire" do you mean ground? So it would be 3 black wires, 3 white wires, and 3 bare copper wires?

Comment: How was it connected before?

Comment: @Craig I've never heard of anybody buying a house where the switches weren't installed. "*New build*" to me means it was built recently, not that it's unfinished. Though; as always, I could be wrong.